# How to separate coefficient and argument of the function?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm trying to make a list with coefficient and argument of the function `f` as below.
`myList` is my input and `output` is my expected output.
I also sent the code I wrote to do this. It works but I wonder how would you do it?
I believe that there are better ways to do this.

```
ClearAll[f]
myList = {f[x], x*f[3 - x], 1/x f[(2 + x)/(1 - 3 x)], 
   3 f[1/x], (1 + x) f[3 x - 1]};
output = {{1, x}, {x, 3 - x}, {1/x, (2 + x)/(1 - 3 x)}, {3, 1/
    x}, {1 + x, 3 x - 1}};
```

my code:

```
In[5530]:= temp1= List@@#&/@myList/.f->Sequence

Out[5530]= {{x},{x,3-x},{1/x,(2+x)/(1-3 x)},{3,1/x},{1+x,-1+3 x}}
    
 In[5531]:= If[Length[#]==1, Insert[#,1,1], #]&/@temp1
Out[5531]= {{1,x},{x,3-x},{1/x,(2+x)/(1-3 x)},{3,1/x},{1+x,-1+3 x}}
```

Comment: `myList /. a_. * f[x_] :> {a, x}`

Comment: Please read up on `OneIdentity`.

Comment: myList  /. (x1_ : 1)  f[x2__]  ->  {x1, x2}